# Suddenly SoundCloud JSON data doesn't parse correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, soundcloud

We have a custom widget that worked fine for years until last week.

It seems that the Json callback is only working now for playlists but not for tracks.

Playlist `/**/jQuery31108094578850496614_1482167143815({"duration":215707,"release_day":null,"permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/puremagnetik/sets/analog-...`

Versus Track

```
{"kind":"track","id":3028745,"created_at":"2010/05/20 18:26:31 +0000","user_id":54749,"duration":74450,"commentable":true,"state":"finished",...
```

See the Track is missing the JQuery element. I'm not sure why this is happening now but if anyone can recommend a fix I would be grateful.

Live with the widget on our site:

Playlist  https://puremagnetik.com/collections/keyboards-ableton-live-pack-kontakt-logic-samples/products/harpsikord-harpsichord-ableton-live-pack-samples

Track  https://puremagnetik.com/collections/glitch-toy-lo-fi/products/bender-circuit-bent-speak-and-spell-ableton-live-pack-kontakt-instrument-apple-logic-samples

Comment: Seems like a few others may have gone through what you're going through. At this point I'd recommend getting in touch with SoundCloud directly.

Comment: Could you show us the code that makes those AJAX calls in case there's a problem there?

Comment: @MMM not sure how to format that in this space but it is making a `
              $.getJSON(apiUrl, function(data) { ` call

Answer (score 0):

This is something that was fixed recently, and should be working again.